# Best way to code this, string to map conversion in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, dictionary

I have a string like

```
def data = "session=234567893egshdjchasd&userId=12345673456&timeOut=1800000"
```

I want to convert it to a map

```
 ["session", 234567893egshdjchasd]
 ["userId", 12345673456]
 ["timeout", 1800000]
```

This is the current way I am doing it,

```
 def map = [:]

 data.splitEachLine("&"){

   it.each{ x ->

     def object = x.split("=")
     map.put(object[0], object[1])

   }

 }
```

It works, but is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know think this is would run any faster, but it does suggest itself in terms of syntactic parsimony:

```
def data = 'session=234567893egshdjchasd&userId=12345673456&timeOut=1800000'
def result = data.split('&').inject([:]) { map, token -> 
    //Split at "=" and return map with trimmed values
    token.split('=').with { 
        map[it[0].trim()] = it[1].trim() 
    }
    map 
}
```

Personally, I like Don's answer for readability and maintainability, but depending on context, this may be appropriate.

**Edit:** This is actually a reformatted one-liner.

Comment: +1 for use of fancy GDK methods (inject) and fancy English phrases (syntactic parsimony)

Comment: you can change the inject innards to token.split('=').with { map << [ (it[0]):it[1] ] } if you _really_ hate readability ;-)

Comment: I liked this solution - until I found that there is a "collectEntries()" function that can be used to build maps. That is much more readable then the "inject()", see my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this is more efficient, but to my eyes, it's a bit simpler (YMMV)

```
def data = "session=234567893egshdjchasd&userId=12345673456&timeOut=1800000"
def map = [:]

data.split("&").each {param ->
    def nameAndValue = param.split("=")
    map[nameAndValue[0]] = nameAndValue[1]
}
```

Comment: I wrote a quick and dirty Groovy script (possibly quite flawed) comparing the 3 techniques mentioned and consistently Dons method came up fastest. It grabbed 3 query string of various lengths and timed how long for each method, output eg: `Method 1 (ig0774)      [124727794, 2236178, 4806756] total: 131770728
Method 2 (Don)         [2546134, 1174801, 2227867] total: 5948802
Method 3 (Ted Naleid)  [10447068, 1915955, 2840445] total: 15203468`   Good enough for my purposes

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for efficient, regular expressions are where it's at:

```
def data = "session=234567893egshdjchasd&userId=12345673456&timeOut=1800000"
def map = [:]
data.findAll(/([^&=]+)=([^&]+)/) { full, name, value ->  map[name] = value }

println map
```

prints:

```
[session:234567893egshdjchasd, userId:12345673456, timeOut:1800000]
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, it might look a little foreign, but it's really not that complicate.  It just has two (groups), the first group is any character but a "&" or a "=".  The second group is any character besides a "=".  The capture groups are on either side of a "=".

Comment: This is a nice solution, but can be made nicer by making it a functional one-liner:  data.findAll(/([^&=]+)=([^&]+)/) { full, name, value ->  [name, value] }.collectEntries( { it })

Answer (score 3):

After some searching, "collectEntries()" is the magic thing to use, it creates a map element. Work just like "collect()" that creates a list. So given

```
def params = "a1=b1&a2=b2&a3&a4=&a5=x=y"
```

the one-liner is

```
map = params.tokenize("&").collectEntries{ 
          it.split("=",2).with{ 
              [ (it[0]): (it.size()<2) ? null : it[1] ?: null ] 
          }
      }
```

which creates

```
map = [a1:b1, a2:b2, a3:null, a4:null, a5:x=y]
```

Depending how you want to handle the cases "a3" and "a4=" you can also use a slightly shorter version

```
...
[ (it[0]): (it.size()<2) ? null : it[1] ] 
...
```

and then you get this:

```
map = [a1:b1, a2:b2, a3:null, a4:, a5:x=y]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest using split at all.

Split creates a new string, whereas when creating a collection of environment variables, you would probably want a list of maps.

Tokenize both on the initial break (&) and on the nested break (=).  While most interpreters will still work, some may run the split literally, and you'll end up with a list of strings, rather than a list of maps.

```
def data= "test1=val1&test2=val2"
def map = [:]

map = data.tokenize("&").collectEntries {
    it.tokenize("=").with {
        [(it[0]):it[1]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a grails controller, then this is nice and simple:

```
GrailsParameterMap map = new GrailsParameterMap(request)
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsParameterMap.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use Grails, the best way I find is WebUtils the function fromQueryString.

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/util/WebUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's my effort, which initializes and fills the map in one go, and avoids the inject method which I personally find hard to follow:-

```
    def map = data.split('&').collectEntries {
        def kvp = it.split('=').collect { string ->
            string = string.trim()
            return string
    }
    [(kvp[0]): kvp.size() > 1 ? kvp[1] ?: '' : '']
    // the null check is almost certainly overkill so you could use :-
    // [(kvp[0]): kvp.size() > 1 ? kvp[1] : '']
    // this just checks that a value was found and inserts an empty string instead of null 
}
```