# Groovy extract string using regex

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I'm using groovy, and i need to extract the token value from the next string.

> token=aaadsfd-345-4e43a5-93406-afed05f784534cae&UserName=sometest

Comment: Good luck! Head on back when you have a question.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812689/best-way-to-code-this-string-to-map-conversion-in-groovy. I would do it as `url.split(/&/).inject([:]) { map, item -> item.split(/=/).with { map << [(it[0]) : it[1]] } }.token` which is slightly different from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?<=token=).*?(?=&)
```

---

The regex as groovy string

```
/(?<=token=).*?(?=&)/
```